# Why I receive just one line of text in firebase android notifications?

Tags: android, firebase, firebase-cloud-messaging

This is the data I am receiving in onMessageReceived method.

```
***E/received message data: {action=mail_sms, body=Test notification test notification Test..., sound=mySound, title=Test Notification Test notification}***
```

My original message is **Test notification test notification Test Test notification test notification Test Test notification test notification Test Test notification test notification Test** of this length. But in onMessageReceived but what I receive is just this text **Test notification test notification Test...**. How can I solve to receive complete text.

Answer (score 0):

You might need to use addition setStyle() method. So you would need to apply

> NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle

So the code would be added to your notification builder:

```
NotificationCompat.Builder mBuilder = new NotificationCompat.Builder()
 mBuilider.setStyle(new  
    NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
```

Comment: I am already using this.
.setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
                .setContentTitle(title)
                .setStyle(new NotificationCompat.BigTextStyle().bigText(message))
                .setContentText(message)

Comment: The problem is the above Log I pasted is right after onMessageReceived call. Mean before passing notification to builder I am getting this output.

Comment: Here is the code:

public void onMessageReceived(RemoteMessage remoteMessage) {
        super.onMessageReceived(remoteMessage);
        Log.e(TAG, "Status: Message Received");
        if (remoteMessage != null)
        {
            Log.e(TAG, "Data: "+remoteMessage.getData().toString());
            Map<String,String> data = remoteMessage.getData();
            Log.e("received message data", data.toString());
            String mTitle = data.get("title");
            String mMessage = data.get("body");
            String action = data.get("action");
            Intent intent;

Comment: So is this only happening in the logcat? It might be that the logcat is just capping the word limit in your message. But it should still work fine on the app

Comment: No does not work fine in app. I get same message in notification as in logcat.